# Найти запросы, которые исполняются без индексов MYSQL

Tags: mysql, debian

Запускал mysqltuner у себя на сервере. Одной из ошибок была такая:

```
Joins performed without indexes
```

Как я понял, это означает что у меня есть запросы, которые обращаются к тем таблицам, где нету индексов. Как найти эти запросы?

Comment: Нет, Вы неверно поняли. Вернее, наполовину верно. Фраза означает: есть запросы, при построении плана которых использование индексов (если они у таблицы вообще имеются) признано неэффективным, и будет выполняться сканирование таблицы.

Comment: а как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Да в общем никак... только анализируя конкретные проблемные запросы (скажем, попадающие в slow log). Тем более что изменение статистики запросто может поменять план вроде бы вылизанного запроса.